# Attach a debugger to an application inside docker

Tags: docker, debugging, visual-studio-code

[Docker](https://www.docker.com/) is a wonderful tool for running/deploying your application in a well-defined, controlled environment, and is well supported by e.g. the GitLab CI or by MS Azure.

We would like to use it also in the development phase, so that all developers have the same environment available. Of course, we want to keep the image as light as possible and we do not want e.g. any IDE or other development tool inside of it. 
So the actual development takes place outside of docker.

Running our (python) application inside of docker is no problem, but debugging it is not trivial: I do not know of a way to attach a debugger to an application running inside docker. In theory this should be possible, but how does one do it?

Additional info: we use [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), that does have some [docker](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/docker), plugin, but nothing of this sort is mentioned.

Comment: I think you should expose debug port on container and connect your IDE with that port to debug application. Let's take an example in java if you want to debug application you can define debug port on `JAVA_OPTS` same will be there for any other application.

Comment: you are basically right. I provided an answer with some more details below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this is possible, following the same [steps](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_remote-debugging) needed for remote debugging.

The IP address of the docker image can be retrieved through:

```
docker inspect <container_id> | grep -i ip
```

just be sure to add at the beginning of your application:

```
import ptvsd
# Allow other computers to attach to ptvsd at this IP address and port, using the secret
ptvsd.enable_attach(secret=None, address = ('0.0.0.0', 3000))
ptvsd.wait_for_attach()
```

'0.0.0.0' means on all interfaces.

For vscode, the last steps consists in adapting the `python: Attach` configuration, specifying the address and the remote and local roots for your script.

However, for some mysterious reason my breakpoints are ignored.